# Symfony2 Forms children and errors

Tags: php, forms, symfony, error-handling, children

I'm building a site-wide search form and I'm having trouble understanding the Symfony2 Forms structure, regarding children forms and error handling.

My code looks like this:

**Form Type**

```
class SearchType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('q', 'search', array(
                'label' => '',
                'attr' => array(),
            ))
        ;
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\SearchQuery',
            'csrf_protection' => false,
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'search_form';
    }
}
```

**Entity (referred as `data_class` in the Form Type above)**

```
class SearchQuery
{
    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Type(type="string", message="form.search.query.validation.type")
     * @Assert\Length(
     *      min = 3,
     *      max = 50
     * )
     */
    protected $q;

    public function __construct($q = '')
    {
        $this->setQ($q);
    }

    public function __toString() {
        return $this->getQ();
    }

    public function getQ()
    {
        return $this->q;
    }

    public function setQ($query)
    {
        $this->q = $query;
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
$searchForm = $this->createForm(new SearchType());
$searchFormData = array('q' => $q);
$searchForm->submit($searchFormData);

if ($searchForm->isValid()) {
    [...]
}
else {
    // this returns an empty array regardless there are errors or not
    $errors = $searchForm->getErrors(); 

    // this returns errors when they are present
    $errorMessages = $searchForm->getErrorsAsString();
}
```

You might notice on the second line in the controller code, that I'm submitting an array, not a `SearchQuery` object. I've tried that and it doesn't come out well, although I expected this to be the right approach.

Digging in the Symfony documentation and questions here on StackOverflow helped me understand that `getErrors()` ([see it here](https://code.google.com/r/capcom01-noob/source/browse/vendor/symfony/form/Symfony/Component/Form/Form.php?spec=svn55a6f14887ce1e6585f1a053b1bcf262f1c9e151&r=55a6f14887ce1e6585f1a053b1bcf262f1c9e151#766)) never checks children forms and `getErrorsAsString()` ([see it here](https://code.google.com/r/capcom01-noob/source/browse/vendor/symfony/form/Symfony/Component/Form/Form.php?spec=svn55a6f14887ce1e6585f1a053b1bcf262f1c9e151&r=55a6f14887ce1e6585f1a053b1bcf262f1c9e151#780)) does. So I guessed that that's the reason behind the described behaviour and so it was, my form had a child form.

My question is why is there a child form present and how to get rid of it? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed by adding `error_bubbling` to the `q` field in the form type class.

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('q', 'search', array(
            'label' => '',
            'attr' => array(),
            'error_bubbling' => true,
        ))
    ;
}
```

Comment: This should have a thousand upvotes. Saved my day thank you!